# Filter array of objects by given array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I have array of objects in which I need to filter by statuses

```
const data = [
{
     id:1,
     name:"data1",
     status: {
          open:1,
          closed:1,
          hold:0,
          block:1
     }
},
{
     id:2,
     name:"data2",
     status: {
          open:1,
          closed:0,
          hold:4,
          block:1
     }
},
{
     id:3,
     name:"data3",
     status: {
          open:0,
          closed:0,
          hold:4,
          block:0
    }
}
]
```

statuses are in array

```
const statuses = ['open','closed']
```

I would need to filter all data that contains status open and closed bigger than 0.
So result would be

```
   const result = [
    {
       id:1,
       name:"data1",
       status: {
              open:1,
              closed:1,
              hold:0,
              block:1
        }
    }]
```

This is my attempt,

```
const result = data.filter(item => {
            return (
                statuses.forEach(val => {
                    if (item.status[val] > 0)
                        return item   
                })
            )
        })
```

I'm sure I'm missing something here and I would appreciate any kind of help.
Thank you

Comment: Why `.forEach()`? Have a look at its [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) why that is the wrong tool.

Comment: You probably want to use something like [`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) instead of `forEach`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can acheive your goal by using [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method instead of `forEach`, like this:

```js
const data = [ { id:1, name:"data1", status: { open:1, closed:1, hold:0, block:1 } }, { id:2, name:"data2", status: { open:1, closed:0, hold:4, block:1 } }, { id:3, name:"data3", status: { open:0, closed:0, hold:4, block:0 } } ];
const statuses = ['open','closed'];

const result = data.filter( ({status}) => statuses.every(key => status[key] > 0) );

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Just like in the dupe target...

Comment: Please don't answer such obvious duplicates ...

Comment: I want to thank you, for pointing me to this, I didn't know for every function and includes isn't working in the way I want

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `open` and `close` are always equal or bigger than `0`:

```js
const data=[{id:1,name:"data1",status:{open:1,closed:1,hold:0,block:1}},{id:2,name:"data2",status:{open:1,closed:0,hold:4,block:1}},{id:3,name:"data3",status:{open:0,closed:0,hold:4,block:0}}];

let result = data.filter(e => e.status.open && e.status.closed)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: while this will work for that special case it's not very flexible. Ie the states which to look for are hardcoded and cannot be configured via the input array ...

Answer (score -2):

Try this approach:

```
const opened = data.filter((item) => item.status.open === 1);
```

you can add your own checking inside filter. it will return an array with found object.